# Read JSON data from the YAML file

Tags: json, continuous-integration, gitlab, yaml, continuous-deployment

I have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` the file that I use to install a few plugins (craftcms/aws-s3, craftcms/redactor, etc) in the publishing stage. The file is provided below (partly):

```
# run the staging deploy, commands may be different baesed on the project
deploy-staging:
  stage: publish
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: 127.0.0.1:2375

    # ...............
    # ...............


    # TODO: temporary fix to the docker/composer issue
    - docker-compose -p "ci-$CI_PROJECT_ID" --project-directory $CI_PROJECT_DIR -f build/docker-compose.staging.yml exec -T craft composer --working-dir=/data/craft require craftcms/aws-s3
    - docker-compose -p "ci-$CI_PROJECT_ID" --project-directory $CI_PROJECT_DIR -f build/docker-compose.staging.yml exec -T craft composer --working-dir=/data/craft require craftcms/redactor
```

I have a `JSON` file that has the data for the plugins. The file is `.butler.json.` provided below,

```
{
  "customer_number": "007",
  "project_number": "999",
  "site_name": "Welance",
  "local_url": "localhost",
  "db_driver": "mysql",


  "composer_require": [
      "craftcms/redactor",
      "craftcms/aws-s3",
      "nystudio107/craft-typogrify:1.1.17"
],
  "local_plugins": [
  "welance/zeltinger",
    "ansmann/ansport"
 ]
}
```

How do I take the plugin names from the `"composer_require"` and the `"local_plugins"` inside the `.butler.json` file and create a for loop in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to install the plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't *create a loop* in `.gitlab-ci.yml` since YAML is not a programming language. It only describes data. You could use a tool like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to query for your values (`cat .butler.json | jq '.composer_require'`) inside a script, but you cannot set variables from there (there is a [feature request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2793) for it).

You could use a templating engine like [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) (which is often used with YAML, e.g. by Ansible and SaltStack) to generate your `.gitlab-ci.yml` from a template. There exists a command line tool [j2cli](https://github.com/kolypto/j2cli) which takes variables as JSON input, you could use it like this:

```
j2 gitlab-ci.yml.j2 .butler.json > .gitlab-ci.yml
```

You could then use Jinja expression to loop over your data and create corresponding YAML in `gitlab-ci.yml.j2`:

```
{% for item in composer_require %}
  # build your YAML
{% endfor %}
```

Drawback is that you need the processed `.gitlab-ci.yml` checked in to your repository. This can be done via [pre-commit-hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) (before each commit, regenerate the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and if it changed, commit it along with other changes).

Comment: I tried it from the command line and I think this is the best I can achieve atm. Would you please tell me how to do inside from the python code?

Comment: Note: you will need to install `jinja2` and `jinja-cli` using the pip before you may tried the answer

Comment: I can do it as `os.system("jinja2 gitlab-ci.yml.j2 .butler.json > .gitlab-ci.yml")` from the Pyhto code though.

Comment: In Python, you can do `import jinja2, json; tpl = jinja2.Template(source); tpl.render(json.loads(input_str))` where `source` and `input_str` are strings read from the files.

Comment: Ok and how to write in the .gitlab-ci.yml file afterwards?

Comment: I have faith that you'll get thorough answers searching on SO for „*writing to file in Python*“ :).

Comment: Thanks you so much.